# Rearrange positive and negative integers keeping order of elements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, stl, comparator

```
bool comp(int a, int b)
{

if((a >= 0 && b >= 0) || (a < 0 && b < 0))
    return false;

if ((a >= 0) && (b < 0))
    return false;
}

std::array<int, 9> arr = { -12, 11, -13, -5, 6, -7, 5, -3, -6 };
std::sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),comp);

for (auto x : arr) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

Output:

> -12 -13 -5 -7 -3 -6 11 6 5

As i was going through the code and came across this comparator function.
I tried to find how comparator really works in sort, But didnt able to understand. For increasing and decreasing numbers through comparator is very easy. Please explain how this one is working .

Comment: Something seems wrong. If a is less than zero and b is not the control falls of the end of the function without returning anything. Does this compile without errors or warnings?

Comment: it is working fine without any errors.

Comment: "return true" is missing at the end of the comp function

Comment: `comp` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of reaching a closing brace without encountering a `return` statement.

Comment: Really? With what compiler? I just compiled a version with gcc-8.1 and got `test.cpp:12:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]`. To be fair, I get the same sort if I add a `return true;` line, but this definitely seems like UB.